# php regex parsing, keep the contents of the tag intact

Tags: php, regex

input string:

```
<sometag> valid content .....
....line break    some more valid content</sometag>
```

output string:

```
    valid content.....
......line break some more valid content
```

Please let me know how to do it, thanks.

Comment: I don't mind if someone posts the stupid link (even if it's irrelevant as usual).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = '<sometag> valid content .....
....line break    some more valid content</sometag>';

$string = preg_replace('/<[^>]+>/', '', $string);
```

Comment: That'll nuke the entire string. your `.+` is greedy and will suck up EVERYTHING between the very first `<` and the very last `>` in the whole string.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `strip_tags()` PHP function instead of a regular expression. [See manual.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

```
<?php
  $str = "<sometag> valid content .....
  ....line break    some more valid content</sometag>";
  echo strip_tags($str);

  //valid content .....
  //....line break    some more valid content
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$oldstring = "<sometag> valid content ..... ....line break    some more valid content</sometag>";

$newstring = preg_replace('/\b<sometag>\b/', '', $oldstring); 
$newstring = preg_replace('/\b</sometag>\b/', '', $newstring);
$newstring = preg_replace('<br/>', '', $newstring);
```

assuming by line break you mean `<br/>`